# I couldn't change color of diagonal line in 16*16 label matrix. What's my issue here?

Tags: vb.net, matrix

16*16 matrix is coming to my screen when I start the program. But when I click diagonal button, diagonal line isn't red. That does not change.

my code :

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim etk As New Label 'i define the matrix as etk

    Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 0 To 15
            For j = 0 To 15
                Dim etk As New Label
                Me.Panel.Controls.Add(etk)
                etk.Name = i
                etk.Tag = j
                etk.Size = New Size(26, 26)
                etk.BackColor = Color.Black
                etk.Location = New Point(30 * i + 10, 30 * j + 10)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub diagonal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        For i = 0 To 15
            For j = 0 To 15
                etk.Name = i
                etk.Tag = j
                If i = j Then
                    etk.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

thanks for your interests..

Comment: Its all about scope.  the NEW in Form Load creates a new label -- it is not the one you declared at the form level (*because* it is New).  New and `Dim/Private` do not always automatically go together.  `Dim/Private` DECLARES the object variable, use that at the form level.  `New` creates a new instance, remove that from Form Load.  And since you create a bunch in the loop, the form level one will only refer to the last - get the control from the Controls collection instead, or save them to a list(of Label)

Comment: why? that is looking hard way to reach purpose. could you tell more please

Comment: What @Plutonix is trying to say is that you have two different `etk` variables declared.  One is a field (the "form-level" one), and the other is a local variable declared inside the `For` loop.  Code referencing the `etk` variable inside that for loop will be interpreted as referring to the local variable, since, in that scope, that local variable overrides the form-level one.  Code outside of that loop will be referring to the form-level one.  In any case, as Plutonix also said, Objects and Variables are two different things.

Comment: Your code creates 257 `Label` objects, even though it only declares two variables.  The declaration of the form-level variable includes a `New` clause, which causes a new `Label` object to be created, even though it's never shown.  The `For` loop creates another 256 `Label` objects, even though it only has a single variable to reference one of them at any given time.

Comment: your form level `etk` variable serves no purpose - it can only ever refer to one single label - but you create a bunch of them in that loop.

Comment: simply, i say etk2 instead of etk in second loop. but not working.

Comment: unless you save the labels created to a list or array (because you create many of them), you cant use one variable to refer to the all.  the alternative is as in @StevenDoggart 's answer: fish them out of the controls collection

Answer (score 2):

First, the names of your dynamically loaded labels are not unique.  You need to concatenate the x and the y to make it unique:

```
For i = 0 To 15
    For j = 0 To 15
        Dim etk As New Label
        Me.Panel.Controls.Add(etk)
        etk.Name = i & "," & j
        etk.Tag = j
        etk.Size = New Size(26, 26)
        etk.BackColor = Color.Black
        etk.Location = New Point(30 * i + 10, 30 * j + 10)
    Next
Next
```

Then, when you are looping through in the click event, you need to find the existing label by name.  Simply setting the name property on an existing label doesn't do anything to *find* a control.  All that does is alter the one that's already there.  To find a control by name, you can look it up using the name as the key value of the `Controls` property:

```
For i = 0 To 15
    For j = 0 To 15
        If i = j Then
            Dim etk As Control = Me.Panel.Controls(i & "," & j)
            etk.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Or, more simply:

```
For i = 0 To 15
    Dim etk As Control = Me.Panel.Controls(i & "," & i)
    etk.BackColor = Color.Red
Next
```

Comment: That's not very helpful.  Saying "it is not working" doesn't give me any information by which I can help you solve your problem.  It works fine for me.  I just copied the code into a test project and it worked fine.